# ¿Cómo asignar variable carácter?

Tags: c

¿Cómo hacer que la variable `idn` tome el valor de `id`? ¿y me imprima `idn`?

Éste es mi código:

```
int main() {
    //variables
    int n, peso, cilin, anio, origen, i, m, p;
    float millas, desp, acelera, cf, millasT, pesoT, rendi, tanke, tankev;
    char id[10], idn[10];
    FILE *in;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fscanf(in,"%s %f %d %f %f %d %f %d %d",
               id, &millas, &cilin, &desp, &cf, &peso, &acelera, &anio, &origen);
        if ((desp > 0) && (millas > 0)) {
            tanke = (desp / millas);
            if(tanke > tankev) {
                tankev = tanke;
                idn[10] = id[10]; //variables id
            }
        }
        if (anio == 80) {
            millasT = millas + millasT;
            m=m+1;
        }
        if(anio == 77) {
            pesoT=peso + pesoT;
            p = p + 1;
        }
        if(millas > rendi) {
            rendi = millas;
        }
    }
    pesoT = pesoT / p;
    printf("%.2fn", pesoT);

    millasT = millasT / m;
    printf("%.3fn", millasT);

    printf("%.2fn", rendi);
    printf(" %sn %.2fn", idn, tankev);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cual es el comportamiento que obtienes? Que errores presenta el codigo?

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo completo?

Comment: Tienes muchos errores en este código variables sin valor in, n, id[], idn[], tu código no esta completo, que valores tendría idn[10]?

Comment: idn[10] no sería válido porque idn tiene un tamaño de 10 (entonces el mayor índice sería 9), ¿no?

Comment: los valores vienen de un archivo, los scaneo y los imprimo, el codigo no esta porque no lo agrege

Comment: Copias una cadena (`%s`) en `id` sin estar seguro de que ésta ocupe menos de 10 caracteres, haces un bucle con la variable `n` como límite la cuál tampoco tiene valor inicial, te pasas de rosca al indexar `idn` e `id` en 10 siendo el último elemento 9. Haces una pregunta sobre dos arregos de 10 elementos y pegas decenas de líneas no relacionadas... así que pregunto **exáctamente ¿qué necesitas hacer?**.

Answer (score 1):

Las variables que quieres asignar no son de tipo carácter, son arrays de caracteres de tamaño 10 (`char id[10],idn[10];`). En C para copiar de un array a otro no basta con asignar, hay que copiar la memoria y eso se haría con funciones como [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/), [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy) o similares.

Si quieres copiar el contenido de la variable `id` a `idn` usando `memcpy`, la sintaxis es `memcpy(destino, origen, tamaño)`, por lo que tendrías que sustituir la asignación que tienes en el código por algo como esto:

```
memcpy(idn, id, 10);
```

Esto copia 10 bytes (el tamaño de `id` e `idn`) desde la posición de memoria apuntada en `id` a la posición de memoria apuntada por `idn`.

Answer (score 0):

cuando a la variable le pones corchetes [] (Ej: miVar[5]) estas expresando que esa variable va a tener una longitud de 5 caracteres.
Creo que los valores deberias asignarselos luego (es decir, dejar en blanco []) 
y luego realizar la asignacion mediante una funcion u otro valor predefinido!

Answer (score 0):

No has inicializado *n*, debes inicializar n para poder efectuar el bucle.

Para asignar un solo caracter en ese bucle debería ponerse así :

```
idn[i] = id[i];
```

Para ello has de efectuar una entrada de un solo caracter en scanf en cada ciclo, entonces en esa posición de variable en el scanf, debe corresponder así :

```
scanf (in,"%c",.., &id[i],..);
```

Puedes copiar la cadena completa despues del bucle, fuera del mismo. Para copiar los valores de una matriz a otra, se han de asignar desde cada elemento a cada elemento, o bien para char[] usando funciones como :

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

Con ese código repites *n* veces la entrada de teclado a *id*, en cada bucle se sobrescribe el valor del array de carácteres *id*, y no lo aplicas en dicho ciclo antes de volver a sobreescribirlo en el siguiente ciclo. De esa manera, al guardar su contenido en el archivo solo se guardaría la ultima cadena introducida, perdiendose las anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

La asignación entre vectores tipo carácter no es correcta, debes usar las funciones ya comentadas, o también esta:

```
sprintf(idn, "%s", id);
```